# perl regular expressions substitution/replacement using variables with special characters

Tags: regex, perl, special-characters

Okay I've checked previous similar questions and I've been juggling with different variations of quotemeta but something's still not right.

I have a line with a word ID and two words - the first is the wrong word, the second is right.
And I'm using a regex to replace the wrong word with the right one.

```
$line = "ANN20021015_0104_XML_16_21 A$xAS   A$xASA";
@splits = split("\t",$line);
$wrong_word = quotemeta $splits[1];
$right_word = quotemeta $splits[2];
print $right_word."\n";
print $wrong_word."\n";

$line =~ s/$wrong_word\t/$right_word\t/g;

print $line;
```

What's wrong with what I'm doing?

### Edit

The problem is that I'm unable to retain the complete words - they get chopped off at the special characters. This code works perfectly fine for words without special characters.

The output I need for the above example is:

```
ANN20021015_0104_XML_16_21      A$xASA   A$xASA
```

But what I get is

```
ANN20021015_0104_XML_16_21      A   A
```

Because of the `$` character.

Comment: What indications do you get that something is wrong with what you are doing? Give errors, expected output and actual output. Is `$xAS` and `$xASA` variables that you intended to interpolate into `$line`?

Comment: Otherwise, your first line needs to be in single quotes!

Answer (score 3):

**ETA:**

Since you get:

```
ANN20021015_0104_XML_16_21      A   A
```

When you want:

```
ANN20021015_0104_XML_16_21      A$xASA   A$xASA
```

My suspicions are as follows:

- You are not intentionally interpolating the variables `$xAS` and `$xASA`, so because they are undefined, they just add the empty string to `$line`, which is visible in your output. E.g. `"A$xAS"` is expanded into `"A" . undef`.
- You are not using `use warnings`, so you do not get information about this error.

**Solution:**

Use `use strict; use warnings;`. Always. They save you a lot of time.

When assigning, use single quotes instead to avoid interpolation of variables:

```
$line = 'ANN20021015_0104_XML_16_21 A$xAS   A$xASA';
```

Old answer:

Since you do not say what goes wrong, it's just guesswork from my end.

I can see a possible accidental interpolation of the variables `$xAS` and `$xASA`, which you can solve by either escaping the dollar sign, or by using single quotes on that `$line` assignment.

You can also build your new string by using `join`, rather than a regex, e.g.:

```
$line = join "\t", @splits[0,2,2];
```

Answer (score 3):

- If you had used `strict` it would have told you that you must declare variables `$xAS` and `$xASA`.
- If you had used `warnings`, it would have told you that you were concatenating an uninitialized variable.

Hence the common admonishment: "use strict, use warnings".

You simply need to either put the string in [*non-interpolated* quotes](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/interpolation.html#Non_interpolated_str) ( `''`, `q{}` ) or *escape* the *sigil* (`$`) so that it doesn't try to [*interpolate*](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/interpolation.html#Interpolated_string) what it thinks is a variable.

- `""` are quotes that will mess with your string
- `''` are quotes that won't

**Lesson**: use *single quotes* unless you *want* interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't in your substitution; the problem is in the very first line of your code example.

```
$line = "ANN20021015_0104_XML_16_21 A$xAS   A$xASA";
```

tries to interpolate the variables `$xAS` and `$xASA` into `$line`, and interpolates nothing because those variables are empty. Use single quotes instead of double quotes so that the string doesn't interpolate.

Had you turned on `warnings` it would have warned you about the fact that you're interpolating an uninitialized variable, and had you turned on `strict 'vars'` it wouldn't have let you use the undeclared `$xAS` and `$xASA` at all.

Finally, you don't have to `quotemeta` the right side of a substitution; only the left.

Comment: They are actually interpolating two variables, `$xAS` and `$xASA`, not `$x`.

Comment: Only use double quotes when you want to interpolate. :)